# SQL Command for Querying the database?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-administration, command-line

Sorry for my lame question I am new to the databases and SQL, Is the any SQL command for the finding out how many people are living in london from the database below?

```
.....................
Name      | City   
.....................
John      | London  
Watson    | New York  
Sherlock  | London  
Holmes    | Berlin  
Mycroft   | innsbruck  
.....................
```

Secondly, are the commands for PostgresSQL, MySQL, SQLlite same?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you start here: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Give a start by typing mysql for dummies..it will really help..i started in same way a long back...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out the syntax difference of queries in various DBMS (`MySQL , Postgres and SQLLite`).

In my opinion this query should be similar in all three DBMS.

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS "No of Peoples" FROM TableName WHERE City = 'London';
```

Comment: `as 'No of Peoples'` is invalid SQL. Identifiers are quoted using double quotes, not single quotes (at least in standard SQL, e.g. Postgres). So it should be `as "No of People"`

Answer (score 0):

Select count(name) from your_db_name where city='London'